# Download SVG data image with FirebaseStored

Tags: android, kotlin, svg, firebase-storage

I want to download an image in svg that is in the FirebaseStore, using data method, but the bitmap conversion returns null.
I need returns the svg image and put on the screen

```html
    private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
    private lateinit var storage: FirebaseStorage
    private lateinit var storageRef: StorageReference


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        auth = Firebase.auth
        storage = Firebase.storage
        storageRef = storage.reference
        val fileRef = storageRef.child("CFM/cfm2.back.svg")
        
        downloadImgData(fileRef)

    }

    private fun downloadImgData(fileRef: StorageReference?){
        if (fileRef != null) {

            val ONE_MEGABYTE = (1024 * 1024).toLong()

            fileRef.getBytes(ONE_MEGABYTE)
                .addOnSuccessListener { bytes ->
                    val bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.size)

                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp)

                    textview.text = fileRef.name
                }
                .addOnFailureListener { exception ->

                    Toast.makeText(this, exception.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
        }
```

Comment: Have you checked that `bytes` is `not null`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Pixplicity's Sharp](https://github.com/Pixplicity/sharp) for loading SVG images into `ImageView`.
It provides method to load svg image from `InputStream` into `ImageView`.

`ByteArray` obtained from Firebase Storage can be converted to `InputStream` by calling `bytes.inputStream()`.

Add the library dependency

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.pixplicity.sharp:library:[VERSION_HERE]@aar'
}
```

This loads the SVG image to imageView

```
val stream = bytes.inputStream()
Sharp.loadInputStream(stream).into(imageView)
stream.close()
```

Finally the function looks like,

```
private fun downloadImgData(fileRef: StorageReference?) {
    if (fileRef != null) {
        val ONE_MEGABYTE = (1024 * 1024).toLong()

        fileRef.getBytes(ONE_MEGABYTE)
            .addOnSuccessListener { bytes ->
                val stream = bytes.inputStream()
                Sharp.loadInputStream(stream).into(imageView)
                stream.close()

                textview.text = fileRef.name
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                Toast.makeText(this, exception.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
    }
}
```